# Can't combine static element and in Angular for getting ElementRef

Tags: angular, directive, angular-dynamic-components

I tried to get index of child component in *ParentComponent*. My structure of *ParentComponent* was

```
<mat-toolbar>
  <ng-container #buttonContainer>
    <chameleon-ng-button [config]="buttonAdd"></chameleon-ng-button>
  </ng-container>
</mat-toolbar>

<ng-template #tmpButton let-config>
  <chameleon-ng-button [config]="config"></chameleon-ng-button>
</ng-template>
```

I init buttonContainer like this

```
@ViewChild('buttonContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: true })
protected buttonContainer: ViewContainerRef;
```

With this, I hope I could have default component (buttonAdd) and could load other button dynamicly using

```
const buttonTmp = this.tmpButton.createEmbeddedView({
   $implicit: config,
});

this.buttonContainer.insert(buttonTmp);
```

After seeks for a while, I still doesn't understand why I  couldn't get index of my *ButtonAdd* by this way
`this.buttonContainer.length`

I got empty array instead of 1. Any answer will be appreciate :)

Comment: How do you initialize `buttonContainer` in your typescript??

Comment: Try using a div instead of ng-template for your button container

Comment: Yes, I have initialize button Container in my component.ts
@ViewChild('buttonContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: true })
  protected buttonContainer: ViewContainerRef;